# Isn't this a ratio variable?

Tags: ratio

Question: State whether the following variable is an interval or ratio variable?
i) Number of car sales per year
The solution states that it's an interval variable.
But that's wrong. For the variable number of car sales per year a meaningful absolute 0 exists. 0 means, they didn't sell any car, therefore, it's a ratio variable. Or do I miss something?

Comment: I have never encountered the terms "ratio variable" and "interval variable" before. Could you state how your book (or whatever it is you have) _defines_ the two terms?

Comment: See [What is the difference between ordinal, interval and ratio variables?](https://www.graphpad.com/support/faq/what-is-the-difference-between-ordinal-interval-and-ratio-variables-why-should-i-care/)

Comment: As far as I can tell from @MauroALLEGRANZA's link, the number of car sales per year is a ratio variable.

Comment: Most "counting" variables are ratio variables.

Comment: Agreed; I'm not a specialist, but according to the link above, the "sales per year" has an "absolute $0$". Thus, it must be a *ratio* and not an *interval*.